# Excel: Update all pivot tables without updating connections

Tags: excel, connection, odbc, pivot-table, updates

I have a question for which I can't find solution.

On Excel, I get data from an SQL query using ODBC. Doing that I have a connection. I expand data from this connection on a sheet named "Details"

Based on this Details sheet, I created many pivot tables, something like 50.
Why do I base my pivot tables directly on the sheet and not the connection?

Because the user want to be able to add or remove data manually from the Details sheet, after having updated the connection with current data, and then update pivot tables with this manually transformed sheet.

The problem is, when I "update all" on Excel, it recalculates pivot tables but also the connection, erasing this way the manual transformations the user did, which is not what I want at this step.

Do you know how I can update quickly all 50 pivot tables without updating the connection?
I can select pivot table table one by one and just update it, but it is not a quick solution ^^

Thanks for answers